# How do you call the intersection with barrier and you can always right turn?

Tags: terminology, highway-engineering, traffic-intersections

[image]

In the photo above I can name the first 3 intersection

a) Regular intersection

b) T intersection

c) Skewed intersection

I am having a hard time on identifying the fourth intersection, what do you call that one?

Comment: Can you explain what the "barrier" implies? It looks like there's fewer lanes in the East leg; which lanes coming from the South can turn right, and why does this differ from condition "a" ?

Comment: The barrier allows all the vehicle on that lane  to right turn regardless of the color of the traffic light because they have their own lane; whereas in condition A they need to consider the traffic light, maybe there is a pedestrian so they still need to wait before they can right turn.

Answer (score 3):

In UK terminology, your separate turning lane would be called a "filter lane" ( see e.g. [Collins dictionary definition](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/filter-lane)). This definition doesn't mean that you can *always* turn in that lane, it means that this lane is exclusively for turning; traffic in it may or may not have to wait for a green light.

I might therefore be tempted to call it a "crossroads with filter lanes". (I would call your situation **a** a "crossroads" rather than a "regular intersection". But then I'd also use the word "junction" rather than "intersection"...

Answer (score 2):

This is probably an example of a *channelized intersection*, where you have [right turn bays](http://safety.fhwa.dot.gov/intersection/conventional/signalized/fhwasa13027/ch11.cfm#e1114) that split from the main road just before the intersection:

References:

[Individual Movement Treatments - FHWA](http://safety.fhwa.dot.gov/intersection/conventional/signalized/fhwasa13027/ch11.cfm)